# Can I create a shorthand for folder names, to hide real name in git?

Tags: git

I would like to have a shorthand for a path, so what my `/home/myUser/file` looks like `$HOME/file` in git. This is because I also have `/etc/file` in the same repo and I don't want to reveal the actual name of home folder.

Is this possible to do?

For context, I have a `~/.dotfiles/` containing the repo but using an alias `alias dg='git --git-dir ~/.dotfiles/.git --work-tree=/'` to vc it, so that I don't have to have my filesystem root in git.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Where exactly are you concerned about your home directory appearing in the repository?

Comment: Can you use symbolic links?

Comment: That's the only way I can think of doing it. I have a feeling this is something I could have a script do for me, by tinkering in `.git/`.  Maybe?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is a bad idea to create a `.git` repository at the top level of an entire file system.  So you would never have `/etc/file` and `/home/username/file`: you would instead have one repository holding `file`, which goes into `/etc`, and a separate repository holding `file`, which goes into `/home/username`.

In practice, of course, this is a bit of a problem: you might want to have a file named `config` that contains some *default* entire-machine-wide settings that should probably go into some `/etc` directory—whether that's `/etc` `/etc/defaults` or or `/usr/local/etc` or whatever, based on the OS–but also have that repository contain a file named `config` that's a more-local configuration.

The standard practical *solution* to this problem is to provide multiple files with *different names*, such as:

```
config.defaults
config.example1
config.sample2
```

where the `defaults` file goes into the `etc`-like machine-wide installation, and the various `example` or `sample` files are for various users.  Importantly, **the actual configuration for the software is not stored in the source repository at all**.  The *actual* configuration that you use, on your machine and/or in your personal settings, is stored in a totally-separate repository, where nobody else has to see it and none of its details can accidentally leak into the to-be-shared-with-others repository.

This means that installing the software requires a special step, during which the configuration is created if it does not already exist.  But that's a *good thing*, because now the software can be upgraded—or rolled back—without overwriting the configuration that already exists.